# Is it possible to detect slicing of an exception after catch by value?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Andrei Alexandrescu held a talk at the last [C++ and Beyond regarding systematic error handling](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C).
I like the Expected template pattern and adapted it to Visual Studio 2010 because the compiler does not support so far the extended unions. So I wrote a UnitTest to check that everything works. Then I came to the point that I wanted to check that the detection of a sliced exception works. But it didn't.

I did not want to paste the complete code here so I tried to reduced it the point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <typeinfo>

class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
  MyException()
    : std::exception()
  {}
  virtual const char* what() const { return "I come from MyException"; }
};

void hereHappensTheFailure()
{
 throw MyException();
}

template <class E>
void detector(const E& exception) 
{
  if (typeid(exception) != typeid(E)) 
  {
    std::cout << "Exception was sliced" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Exception was not sliced" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    hereHappensTheFailure();
  }
  catch (std::exception ex) // intentionally catch by value to provoke the problem
  {
    detector(ex);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But the slicing was not detected. So do I have an error in my test, does this not work with VS2010 or does the pattern not work at the end? (Just edited, because gcc 4.7.2 on [ideone](http://ideone.com/zcrCuH) did not liked it)
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're attempting to do is illegal: `std::exception` is abstract, and thus you cannot slice to it. Even then, once you've sliced an object, it's generally impossible to tell what the source was, unless you have some sort of reference to it.

Comment: @NathanErnst - `std::exception` is not abstract.

Comment: @PeteBecker, my bad. I forgot there's just no way to specify what `what()` returns without inheriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. Slicing converts the exception from MyException to std::exception. Since you're letting the template detect the type automatically it's going to choose the same type as the argument - it's guaranteed to be the same.

Call it like this instead:

```
detector<MyException>(ex);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this throw an error about illegal cast from `std::exception` to `MyException`?

Comment: @soon, I'm not sure what cast you're referring to?

Comment: You specify `E` as `MyException`, but pass `std::exception` object. So, we have a conversion from `std::exception` to `MyException`, but I don't see any allowable constructor for it. Am I missed something?

Comment: @MarkRansom and (soon) I can follow your thoughts. I added a what() method and overwrote so the base method from std::exception but I still have the same problem, the slicing is not detected. As far as I understood Alexandrescu that should be the trick, to check via typeid if the as (const E& exception) object differs from the one that was actually deduced by the template argument.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the only way to achieve this would be to use runtime polymorphism exceptions: Add virtual functions to your exception class, probably just returning the this pointer, and you will be able to distinguish a spliced object from an unspliced one. Like this:

```
class B;
class A {
    virtual B* toB() { return NULL; }
};
class B {
    B* toB() { return this; }
};
```

Later on, you can do on any A object that could be a B Object:

```
class A* foo = bar();
class B* fooB = foo->toB();
if(fooB) {
    //whatever
}
```

As long, as you don't have any virtual functions in your class, C++ actually forbids you to be able to notice splicing, simply because it asserts that no virtual function table pointer will be present in the object to ensure compatibility with C-structs. But that pointer would be needed to tell the two cases apart.

Note, however, that I am not sure on whether this will work as long as you don't create the exception object with 'new'. If your exception is copied into a variable of the base class type, the resulting object will definitely be of that base class type, not of the derived type it was created from. 'throw new MyException()' should work, though.